# Accessing user name in SAML SSO failure handler in spring

Tags: spring-saml

I am using a spring SAML for intergrating spring SAML SSO. The issue I am facing right now is how to get the user name in my custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.

I have created my own SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler and onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) method how do i get the access to the username over here ?

Comment: If the authentication has failed, you can't trust any contained username anyway, can you?

Comment: yes you are right but i just want to audit the username by which invalid authentication is been made

Comment: Let me give you more background on this. What i want to achieve it over here is auditing functionality for successful and failures login information along with some more information from the httpservletRequest object like request.getRemoteAddr() .  Initially i though of doing this auditing inside failure handler as i ma having a access to the request object but in failure handler in case of SAML auhentication failure i do not have access to the username. Now i am thinking of doing the auditing inside the provider let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: also could not get the username, just token, like I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639065/spring-saml-authentication-failure-handler-and-logging/46690078#46690078. Maybe it helps :)